# .net loads property when you check for null before setting property

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

```
private CompanySetting _companySettings= null;
    public CompanySetting CompanySettings
    {
        get
        {          
            _companySettings = _companySettings ?? getCompanySettings();
            return _companySettings;
        }
        set
        {
            _companySettings = value;
        }
    }
```

I have the above property in my viewmode. I started noticing that when I instantiate this class, without calling the get method of the property, the property is automatically set. Meaning that the getCompanySettings is called thereby loading the companysettings property.
I have even put a breakpoint in getCompanySettings method and I know that it does not break in there. Is this a .net thing?

Comment: Put breakpoints in the setter & getter.

Comment: Sounds like you're using some kind of DI container that's resolving a dependency and setting it for you. Check by using a breakpoint in the setter.

Comment: How do you know its set?  Is the debugger reading the property in a watch?

Comment: Note that your method of lazily instantiating `CompanySettings` is not thread-safe. Consider using `Lazy<CompanySetting>` if your application is multi-threaded.

Comment: I have gone through the obvious Bob before posting the question. It does not break in the getter nor the setter.

Comment: I know that it was set because the debugger was reading the property and I was able to watch

Comment: The application is not multi-threaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Visual Studio debugger, it is probably configured to automatically evaluate property getters because they are assumed to be pure (i.e. no side effects from evaluating them). If you have a property getter which does *not* behave this way, you need to add the [`DebuggerBrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerbrowsablestate.aspx) attribute to prevent it from being evaluated by the debugger.

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public CompanySetting CompanySettings
{
    get
    {          
        _companySettings = _companySettings ?? getCompanySettings();
        return _companySettings;
    }
    set
    {
        _companySettings = value;
    }
}
```